# Tools for monitoring when new gem versions are released?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Does anyone know of any tools to monitor and alert me when new versions of gems named in my Gemfile are released?

It could be as simple as a rake task that reports my current version and the latest version, or as fancy as a background process that logs messages to the console whenever new versions are available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bundler 1.1 introduced the command

```
bundle outdated
```

But, as you mentioned, for those with v 1.0, the [bundle-outdated](https://github.com/scoop/bundle_outdated) gem exists.

Comment: I didn't, but that's apparently an option for those who haven't upgraded to bundler 1.1 yet

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this site: [bundle watcher](http://www.bundlewatcher.com/)

You just upload your gem file or link to it, and then you are notified via RSS when an update is available.

Comment: bundle watcher seems to be shut down :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same need but not only for bundler, also for npm and pacman (archlinux pacman manager) [checkzilla](https://github.com/mickey/checkzilla).

It's extensible so there's also different notifiers (console, email, twitter,..). It's beta software as of now but I'm using it on my servr and it's working quite well.

Answer (score 1):

I am also using [bundle watcher](http://www.bundlewatcher.com), but I've set up an [If This Than That](http://ifttt.com) sequence to email me whenever there is an update. This way I get a proactive notification.

There is also a commercial site called [Gemnasium](https://gemnasium.com/), but I have not used it.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what Gemnasium is doing

Comment: Which is shutting down now. Apparently, they have been acquired by gitlab, see https://gemnasium.com/blog/gemnasium-is-acquired-by-gitlab/

Comment: Exactly. But the features are being ported to GitLab CI/CD directly